# Pagination in author, category, archive and tags pages does not work

Tags: pagination, loop, search, author-template

I have implemented a no-plugin pagination taken from here: http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin

It's works perfecto un normal loop but when I try to use in author pages, categories, archives, tags and search results everything goes bad.

The pagination works but when the link it generate load then everything woes wrong.

The code:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'paged'=>$paged 
);

query_posts( $args );
```

h**p://localhost/?author=1&paged=1 works perfect, load author.php template.

h**p://localhost/?author=1&paged=2 redirects me to home page.

If I change &paged with &page the it works but the stander loop in index.php used paged by default and I want the same paginator working in the hole website.

It's like wordpress do something special with "paged" parameter.

¿Any tip or suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a simular issue to this one with wp-pageNavi: http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/right-way-to-use-query_posts.html.

Taxonomies and archives should use 'page', not 'paged' so use that in the urls to begin with.

Then, to ensure your pagination script works in all locations you can change the way you get your $paged variable.

Something like this should do it:

```
if (is_archive()) {
     $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
} else {
     $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike but unfortunately this is only the way to read is there is page or paged. The code for pagination always generate the paged var and not page o paged selective. I have tried even to make the pagination function to use paged o page but the function use a get_pagenum_link() to generate the link. Ok, I can change the function for another of my own creation but I'm looking always the possibility of using the most standar way of doing things.  Any suggestion please? Thanks again.

Comment: I change to permalinks just to test if work but not. If y load the page http://localhost:8888/opengov/author/deryck/ all fine but when I try to load the second page http://localhost:8888/opengov/author/deryck/page/2/ then I get a 404 error page. The URL is invalid.

Comment: I force http://localhost:8888/opengov/author/deryck/page/1/ to test page one and It works perfects. So, if the 1 changes for 2 then i get the 404 error. Weird and annoying